# n(n+1) as a multiple of 100

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Here's a puzzle I came up with while walking today:

> For how many natural numbers $n$ is the number $n(n+1)$ a multiple of $100$?

- This is true for infinitely many $n$, so "how many" means something like "one in every hundred $n$", an answer in that sort of form.
- There are some brute-forcey ways to do this, but also some nice shortcuts. Checkmark will go (eventually) to the neatest solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider two consecutive numbers $n$ and $n+1$.

> Suppose the first is a multiple of $a$, the second a multiple of $b$.
>  Since consecutive numbers are coprime, $a$ and $b$ are coprime.
>  We want to count all those cases where $a*b=100$, which are therefore the four cases $(a,b) \in \{ (1,100), (100,1), (4,25), (25,4) \}$.
>  In each case we have a pair of modular equations
>  $$n\equiv 0 \mod a \\ n+1\equiv 0 \mod b$$
>  The Chinese Remainder Theorem gives a unique solution modulo $a*b=100$, so there are exactly $4$ solutions in every block of $100$ consecutive numbers, or $1$ in $25$.

**Edit:**
Here's a different, possibly simpler argument:

> Clearly one of the two consecutive numbers needs to be a multiple of $25$. Pick any multiple of $25$.
>  If this is an odd number, then its neighbours are both even and differ by two, so exactly one of its neighbouring numbers is a multiple of $4$, and we get one solution to the problem.
>  If it is even and a multiple of $4$, then it is itself a multiple of $100$ and we can combine it with either of its neighbours, so this gives two solutions to the problem.
>  If it is even but not a multiple of $4$, then it cannot form a solution with either of its neighbours since they are both odd.
>  On average we get one solution for every multiple of $25$.

Comment: Nice, you've managed to count them without explicitly solving the Chinese Remainder Theorem congruences. But there's a trick to shortcut around using CRT.

Comment: Yep, your second argument is pretty much what I was thinking of. Surprisingly enough, CRT isn't (explicitly) needed at all to solve this problem.

Answer (score 20):

First,

> We have $(n,n+1)=1$. So either $4\mid n$ or $4\mid n+1$, and either $25\mid n$ or $25\mid n+1$.

So,

> We have the $n\equiv-1,0\pmod4$ and $n\equiv-1,0\pmod{25}$. After solving, we have $n\equiv0,24,75,99\pmod{100}$ are all the integers that fit the requirement.

---

Edit(More elegant):

> Wait a minute, the author only required us to find the number of solutions! So by CRT, as there are two remainders which we need when $n$ is divided by $4$ and $25$, we have $2\times2=4$ solutions per $25\times4=100$ consecutive integers.

Comment: This is correct (+1), but there's a trick to shortcut around part of this, making it not *just* a standard application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Edited!

Comment: @Randal'Thor Is this your method?

Comment: Sorry for not responding to your edit. I left a comment on Jaap's answer; his second method is what I had in mind. But when I come to accept an answer on this, I'll have a think about whether to accept that one or if anyone else's is simpler / more elegant.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, No, isn’t my method more elegant? I used the property of uniqueness of solution, and found the number of solutions.

Answer (score 8):

In the "degenerate" case:

> Any solution where n=m*100 or n+1=m*100 works.  This occurs twice for every hundred.

In any other case, specific conditions must be met:

> 100 factors as two 2s and two 5s, so those factors must be contained in n and n+1.

However, we can easily narrow it further:

> If n has 2 or 5 as a factor, n+1 does not.  Therefore one term must have two 5s and the other must have 2 twos.  The only adjacent integers satisfying this are 24,25 and 75,76, so n=24 or n=75.  This works for every m*100+n, since m*100 contains two 2s and two 5s.

Combining the two cases:

> 4% of integers satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 4):

> Using the well-known summation formula, $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$, the question is equivalent to how often $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ is a multiple of $50$. To get a multiple of $100$, $n$ and $n+1$ together must contain two factors of $5$. Since $n$ and $n+1$ cannot both be a multiple of $5$, at least one of them is a multiple of $25$.

Now observe that

> if we enumerate the cases of $n=a\cdot 25$ and $n=a\cdot 25 - 1$ for some positive integer $a$ with $n\leq 50$, we get \begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{24} i &= (24\cdot 25)/2 = 3\cdot 4\cdot 25 \equiv 0 \mod 50\\ \sum_{i=1}^{25} i &\equiv 25 \mod 50 & \text{(follows from line above)}\\ \sum_{i=1}^{49}i &= (49\cdot 50)/2 = 49 \cdot 25\equiv 25 \mod 50 \\ \sum_{i=1}^{50} i &\equiv 25 \mod 50 & \text{(follows from line above)}\end{align}
>  Since we work modulo $50$, the values for $n\in [51,100]$ will be those of $[0,50]$ plus $25$. This means $75, 99, 100$ are exactly the values when the summation is $0\mod 50$. So, $24,75,99,100$ are all the solutions in $[1,100]$, and since $\sum_{i=1}^{100} i = 0\mod 50$, these solutions are periodic with a period of length $100$. 
>  Therefore, for every $4$ out of $100$ integers $n$, $n(n+1)$ is a multiple of $100$

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(To reflect a puzzle that came up while walking,
 here’s a general solution that also came up while walking.
 This write-up was reorganized a few days after posting.)</sup>

$\begingroup
  \def \b       #1{ \boldsymbol{#1} }
   \def \F    #1#2{ {\LARGE\strut} \f{#1}{#2} }
    \def \f   #1#2{ { \large #1 \over \large #2 } }
     \def \Q  #1#2{ {  \large\frac{2^{\Large\kern.05em\b{#1}}}{#2} } }
      \def \t   #1{ {\small\textsf{#1}} }
       \def \x    { { \scriptsize\raise.2ex\times}\kern.1em }
        \def \& #1{ &  \kern-.9em #1 \kern-1em & }
         \def \+  { {   \kern.1em + } }
          \def \/ {      \\[-.4ex]    }
$The probability that $n(n\+1)$ is a multiple of $100$ is ...

> $$ { 2^{\large (\textsf{how many distinct prime factors of}~100)} \over 100 } ~=~ { 2^{\large 2} \over 100} ~=~ { 1 \over 25} $$

This works in general for $n(n\+1)$
that might be a multiple of any $m \ge 2$.
(In the puzzle, $m=100$.)

$$ \begin{matrix}
   \begin{matrix} \\     m      \\ \t{(as an example)}  \end{matrix}
&& \begin{matrix} \\  \t{Prime}  \/ \t{factorization} \/ \t{of}~ m  \end{matrix}
&& \begin{matrix} \strut D(m) ~ = \/ \t{how many} \/ \t{distinct prime}
                                   \/ \t{factors of}~ m  \end{matrix}
&& \begin{matrix} {\Large{2^{D(m)} \over \raise.3ex m}} ~ =
                                     \/ \t{probability that}
                                      \/ n(n\+1) ~\t{is a}
                                       \/ \t{multiple of}~ m  \end{matrix}
\\[1ex]\hline  2 &&  2^1               &&  1 && \Q{1}{2}    ~=~ 1       \\
               3 &&  3^1               &&  1 && \Q{1}{3}    ~=~ \F{2}{3} \\
               4 &&  2^2               &&  1 && \Q{1}{4}    ~=~ \F{1}{2}  \\
               6 &&  2^1 \x   3^1      &&  2 && \Q{2}{6}    ~=~ \F{2}{3}   \\
              72 &&  2^3 \x   3^2      &&  2 && \Q{2}{72}   ~=~ \F{1}{18 }  \\
 \boldsymbol{100}&&\b2^2 \x \b5^2      &&\b2 && \t{(already mentioned)}      \\
            4725 &&  3^3 \x 5^2 \x 7^1 &&  3 && \Q{3}{4725} ~=~ \F{8}{4725}
\end{matrix}$$

Sure enough, the probabilities are the same
for $m = 3$ and $m = 6 = 3 \x 2$.
After all, $n(n\+1)$ is always divisible by $2$.

And, sure enough,
$ 2^{\large (\textsf{how many distinct prime factors of}~4725)} {=}~ 8 $
instances of $n(n\+1)$ among the $4725$ values of
$1 \le n \le 4725$ are divisible by $m = 4725 = 3^3 \x 5^2 \x 7^1 $.

$$\small\begin{array}{rrlcrrlrrrlcrrl}
  350 \&\x 351  &=& (        5^2 \x 7 ) \&\x    2 ~\&\x~ 13   \&\x ( 3^3             ) &=&   26 \&\x 4725 \\
 1350 \&\x 1351 &=& (      3^3 \x 5^2 ) \&\x    2 ~\&\x~ 193  \&\x ( 7               ) &=&  386 \&\x 4725 \\
 1700 \&\x 1701 &=& (             5^2 ) \&\x   68 ~\&\x~ 9    \&\x ( 3^3 \x 7        ) &=&  612 \&\x 4725 \\
 3024 \&\x 3025 &=& (        3^3 \x 7 ) \&\x   16 ~\&\x~ 121  \&\x ( 5^2             ) &=& 1936 \&\x 4725 \\
 3374 \&\x 3375 &=& (               7 ) \&\x  482 ~\&\x~ 5    \&\x ( 3^3 \x 5^2      ) &=& 2410 \&\x 4725 \\
 4374 \&\x 4375 &=& (             3^3 ) \&\x  162 ~\&\x~ 25   \&\x ( 5^2 \x 7        ) &=& 4050 \&\x 4725 \\
 4724 \&\x 4725 &=&                     \&{} 4724 ~\&\x~ 1    \&\x ( 3^3 \x 5^2 \x 7 ) &=& 4724 \&\x 4725 \\
 4725 \&\x 4726 &=& ( 3^3 \x 5^2 \x 7 ) \&\x    1 ~\&\x~ 4726 \&{}                     &=& 4726 \&\x 4725
\end{array}$$

**Why this works, with $m = 4725$ as an example:**

1. The combined prime factors of $n$ and $n\+1$
   must include the prime factors of $4725$,
   namely at least three $3$s, two $5$s and one $7$.
2. All $3$s may be factors only of $n$ or only of $n\+1$
   as consecutive numbers have no common factors.
   Same for the $5$s and $7$, so
   $27$ ($\small =3^3 \raise.7ex\strut$),
   $25$ ($\small =5^2 \raise.7ex\strut$)
   and $7$ are, in effect, indecomposable factors.
3. The possibilities of $27$, $25$ or $7$ being factors of a number
   are independent of each other because $27$, $25$ and $7$
   share no common factors.
4. The probability that $27$ is a factor of $n$ or $n\+1$ is $\f{2}{27}$.
   The probability that $25$ is a factor of $n$ or $n\+1$ is $\f{2}{25}$.
   The probability that  $7$ is a factor of $n$ or $n\+1$ is $\f{2}{7}$.
   As these component probabilities are independent,
   multiply them together for the probability that
   $27$, $25$ and $7$ are all present as factors of $n$($n\+1)$:

$$ \small {2 \over 27} \x {2 \over 25} \x {2 \over 7}
        = {2^3 \over 27 \x 25 \x 7} = {8 \over 4725} $$

In general, the resulting probability fraction has:

- **Numerator equal to 2 raised to the power that is the count
  of distinct prime factors** of the number whose multiples are sought.
  (In the puzzle, $m = 100 = \b2^2 \x \b5^2 \raise.3ex\strut$
  has $2$ distinct prime factors.)
  This is because each distinct prime factor
  may appear in either $n$ or $n\+1$.
- **Denominator equal to the number** ($m=100$ in the puzzle)
  whose multiples are sought.
  This is because the denominators of the multiplied component probabilities
  are collectively the prime factors of $m$ raised to their exponents.

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 2):

If we set K=25*a, where a is an odd number, and N=(25*a±1)/4, where N is an integer, then the product K*4N is a multiple of 100.

Comment: All odd numbers  are written as  4x+3 and 4x+1

Answer (score 2):

Brute force approach(python):

```
def multiples_of_hundred(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if ((i * (i+1)) % 100) == 0:
            sum += 1
    return sum/n
```

Returns 4% (0.04) for multiples of 100.

Comment: interestingly, the maximum (when testing the first 10,000 positive integers) is 0.041666..., the value at 24. Also, the minimum, excluding the zeros before 24, is 0.0135135... at 74.

Answer (score 1):

> My strategy is any of n or n+1 have to be divisible by 100 so that nX(n+1) becomes divisible by 100, thus
>  99, 100,
>  199, 200,
>  299, 300,
>  this way; i.e.
>  respectively
>
>  99X100=9900, 100X101=10100
> etc.
>  From 101 to 198 the number of natural number is 98
>  Similarly from 201 to 298  " " " " " " 98

(deleted wrong answer)

But I am worried that I might be missing some other set of numbers which may follow similar criterion as asked by OP.

Edit: As suggested by User EI Guest there are other solutions where

> a factor of n and a factor of n+1 together making 100; ie
>
>  Possibility-1: n is divisible by 4 and n+1 is divisible by 5
>  Such as 24 and 25
>  as well
>  Possibility-2: n is divisible by 5 and n+1 is divisible by 4.
>  Such as 75 and 76

Comment: This isn’t quite right — you’re missing two other solutions per 100 that work! (Namely 24x25 = 600 and 75x76 = 5700.)

Comment: @El-Guest thank you. Yes I missed that possibilities.